# How to switch snap docker from inactive to active?

Tags: server, services, snap, docker, container

Why is it easy to switch `docker` from `inactive` to `active` on AWS:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ sudo snap services
Snap    Service  Startup  Current
docker  dockerd  enabled  active
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ sudo snap stop docker
Stopped.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ sudo snap services
Snap    Service  Startup  Current
docker  dockerd  enabled  inactive
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ sudo snap start docker
Started.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ 
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$ sudo snap services
Snap    Service  Startup  Current
docker  dockerd  enabled  active
ubuntu@ip-172-31-14-19:~$
```

but on my home system it still shows as `inactive` despite [using](https://askubuntu.com/a/858715/45156) `sudo`?

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo snap services
Snap    Service  Startup  Current
docker  dockerd  enabled  inactive
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo snap stop docker
Stopped.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo snap start docker
Started.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo snap services
Snap    Service  Startup  Current
docker  dockerd  enabled  inactive
thufir@dur:~$
```

How do I flip the switch on `docker` to `active`?

There's no [log](https://docs.snapcraft.io/build-snaps/debugging) which I see:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo /snap/bin/snappy-debug.security scanlog hello-world-service
sudo: /snap/bin/snappy-debug.security: command not found
thufir@dur:~$
```